# Training tesseract with connected contours or separate symbols?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to recognize some text with tesseract, but accuracy is still not acceptable. The problem is that font is small and thin with short letter spacing, and after all image processing (adjusting levels, threshold, transform) some letters connect with others or even get cut into two contours. Next image is example of processed image ready to recognition.
[image]

The main question is should I train tesseract with these whole connected contours like 'HUM' or with separate symbols?

All general ideas about image processing and recognition will be greatly appreciated!